# img not respecting height property when parent size is defined

Tags: html, css

I have a column flex container, with one flex child containing an image

```
<div class="flex">
  <p> Test </p>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/E4Os1Fh.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

All elements are given width 100% height 100% along the chain.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How come the image is not respecting the height properties and is taking up more space than the height of its parent element?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ohewn35k/4/

(You need to resize the window to be smaller than the natural image size to see the problem in action)

---

**EDIT: The example in this question seems to be working fine, but it doesn't not work in my actual code. I have stripped my code down in developer tools and uploaded a zip file**

https://www.mediafire.com/file/v32z4xrxnstyd3d/reproduce.7z/file

If you extract the file and open `reproduce.html` you'll see that the image element has a scrollbar as it's expanding passed its available space for some reason.

---

Once I fix this problem, I intend to add `object-fit: contain` to the image so it contains nicely within its available space.

Comment: your `<img src="https://i.imgur.com/E4Os1Fh.png">` is missing the class. should become `<img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/E4Os1Fh.png">`

Comment: @C_Ogoo Sorry, just a mistake in the fiddle. I updated the question to be more like my real code.

Comment: use the object inspector on your `<img>` and find out which (other) styles are applied to the element.

Comment: Yes, I've checked, no other styles. I manually stripped down my page inside the inspector, and CTRL+S. I will upload and add link to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using flexbox.

Your `.flex-item` becomes this:

```css
.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Essentially you're are telling the flex item to use the maximum space available.

You can read about the flex property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: Sorry I do have `flex: 1` in my code if you download my zip file. Just tired, typed the wrong thing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS '.img' selector should just be 'img'

Try this

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/E4Os1Fh.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem in the fiddle, but for some reason in my real code (where I targeted the image correctly) it's still not working.

Comment: @DavidCallanan without the real code I can't be of much help

Comment: @DavidCallanan please consider adding the code directly to the question. I (and I'm sure others feel the same) am not comfortable downloading random zip files from the internet.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm trying to reproduce it on JSFiddle but can't manage to do so. Once I can I will add the code to the question. Thanks for your help anyways